# Setting default `docker run` parameters in Mesos / Marathon

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

We are running a Mesos cluster and just had an issue with one docker container that essentially fork bombed an agent.

Docker has `--pids-limit` setting that would prevent such issues in the future. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

`--pids-limit` is a `docker run` parameter, so it would need to be set for every Marathon application.

Ideally I'd like to set it once somewhere in dockerd / Mesos / Marathon as some default, and let the users override it if they know what they're doing.  However, I can't find a nice simple way to add a default flag/parameter for `docker run`

Any ideas how to best achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by adding `--pids-limit` to [`Parameters` in `DockerInfo`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/2aaf96ecbab316708afb401e43cad2f2f692f687/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L3273-L3277).

Unfortunately Marathon does not support this change but this could be done by [RunSpec Marathon Plugin](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/bff49e1acf6e5d835cb58d3535b6fbde4fc515bb/docs/docs/plugin.md#runspec)